# Programatically set a Google Calendar sharing settings to "Make this calendar public"

Tags: c#, .net, google-calendar-api, gdata-api

I have an application that currently creates Google Apps Calendars, and now need to have the ability to make those calendars public (visible to the world instead of just visible to the organization which appears to be the default).

I have the following code running to create calendars currently:

```
public CalendarEntry CreateCalendar(string title, string summary, string timezone, bool ispublic)
{
    CalendarEntry calendar = new CalendarEntry();
    calendar.Title.Text = title;
    calendar.Summary.Text = summary;
    calendar.TimeZone = timezone;


    Uri postUri = new Uri("https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/owncalendars/full");
    CalendarEntry createdCalendar = (CalendarEntry) _calendarService.Insert(postUri, calendar);

    return createdCalendar;
}
```

All calendars created with this method create calendars only visible to the organization.  How can I set them to be visible publicly?

Answer (score 3):

```
            AclRule aclRule = new AclRule()
            {
                Role = "owner",
                Scope = new AclRule.ScopeData()
                {
                    Type = "user",
                    Value = email.ToString()
                }
            };
            _service.Acl.Insert(aclRule, calendarId).Execute();
```

Comment: adding explanation would have been helpful

Answer (score 0):

According to the Google calendar API, [Access Control Lists (ACLs)](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/acl/patch) look like your solution. Try the PATCH method it shows.